# Prove this linear map $(Tf)(x) = x^2f(x)$ is injective and find the null space

Tags: linear-algebra

> $T$ is the linear map defined by multiplication by $x^2$ such that $(Tf)(x) = x^2f(x)$. Prove that it is is injective and find the null space

I'm confused because I think this map actually is injective. The only time $(Tf)(x) = 0$ for all $x$ is when $f$ is the zero polynomial which means the null space is $\{0\}$ so how is it possible that this map is not injective? Any insights am I missing something? Thank you!

Comment: You should specify the domain and codomain of $T$. Your question is confusing. The title asks to prove that $T$ is injective and then you go on as if it wasn't supposed to be injective, but you think it is.

Comment: Please make sure the body of the question is readable. They are not meant as a continuation of title.

Comment: "how is it possible that this map is not injective?" Who suggested that it was _not_ injective?

Answer (score 3):

Two functions $f$ and $g$ that agree everywhere but disagree at $0$ will be mapped to the same function.

So we do not have injectivity. However, with additional conditions on the functions, such as continuity at $0$, we do have injectivity.

**Added:** For a proof, note that if $x^2f(x)=x^2g(x)$ and $x\ne 0$, then $f(x)=g(x)$. It remains to show that if $f$ and $g$ are continuous at $0$, then $f(0)=g(0)$.

We have $\frac{1}{n^2}f(1/n)=\frac{1}{n^2}g(1/n)$ for any positive integer $n$, and therefore $f(1/n)=g(1/n)$. If $f$ and $g$ are continuous at $0$, then $f(0)=\lim_{n\to\infty} f(1/n)=\lim_{n\to\infty}g(1/n)=g(0)$.

Comment: It's clear from the question that the context is that of polynomials.

Comment: Luckily I mentioned that continuity at $0$ is enough for injectivity, which takes care of things if $f(x)$ is a polynomial.